# TensorFlow.js: Are those two Tensors equal?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensor

I am reading the TensorflowJS documentation. In their example code they state

```
  const xs = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1]);
```

[See here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs)

I am confused since they use a 2 dimensional array here. Does anyone know why?

For completeness, here is the full code snippet.

```
 // Define a model for linear regression.
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));

  // Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
  model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});

  // Generate some synthetic data for training.
  const xs = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1]);
  const ys = tf.tensor2d([1, 3, 5, 7], [4, 1]);

  // Train the model using the data.
  model.fit(xs, ys).then(() => {
    // Use the model to do inference on a data point the model hasn't seen before:
    // Open the browser devtools to see the output
    model.predict(tf.tensor2d([5], [1, 1])).print();
  });
```

Would it not be simpler to use a 1 dimensional array here, since the array does not make use of a second dimension anyways?

```
const xs = tf.tensor1d([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The features `xs` tensor is a two dimensionnal tensor. More generally the features tensor is one dimension bigger than the inputShape of the first layer. The added dimension is the batches dimension which indicates how many elements of shape the inputShape, the model are either trained with or predicted.

In the example, the inputShape being of size `[1]`, the features shape need to be of shape `[b,1]`, therefore a two dimensionnal tensor